# How to install opencv-python in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.8

I'm having problem during the installation of opencv-python in pycharm.
After opening pycharm I click on settings and then project interpreter, I click on '+' and search for the correct module, I started the installation but it fails with

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

Additionally I tried installing it through console but I get the same error.
I also have updated to the last pip version, how can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, it is @OferSadan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT / UPDATE: You can now install through `pip`, support was added to python 3.8

OpenCV is not yet (officially) compatible with python 3.8. this version of python is quite new and lots of pip packages can't be installed on it (yet). You can verify that at the bottom of the [PyPi page for OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Three possible solutions:

1. Downgrade to python 3.7.5 and install the package through pip as you normally would, and wait for an officially supported version before trying again with python 3.8
2. Try building OpenCV from source files yourself. This might require quite a bit of technical knowledge and might ultimately fail anyway without some changes to the source. If you're interested in that solution, start [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html) for windows or [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) for linux
3. There is a pre-built wheel available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) that works with python 3.8, but it is unofficial (but the source here is quite credible) - this is probably the easiest choice to set up

Also, you can track when support will come to python 3.8 in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/253)

Comment: @james no problem, added a link on where you can check the versions

Comment: @james just to update you, the version for python 3.8 is now out and you can install it though pip or through pycharm

Answer (score 6):

Under python 3.8.
Open Anaconda prompt
Then type: **pip install opencv-python**

I hope this is useful for everybody

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because currently in 2021 this method allows installing opencv with Python 3.8

Comment: Also Python 3.9 Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

the solution to use in 3.8 is to download the .whl and install it with pip
example:
pip install D: \ downloads \ opencv_python-4.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl