# OpenCv with Python 3.8

Tags: opencv, python-3.8

Is OpenCv still not compatible with Python 3.8? I have tried everything (google and multiple SO posts including [this one][How to install opencv-python in python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892378/how-to-install-opencv-python-in-python-3-8) and it doesn't seem to work. Since I was able to pip install without many issues I'm assuming that the compatibility issue has been solved.

My download attempts always lead to this: 
**

> C:\Users\Devansh\Downloads> pip install
>   .\opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
>  Processing
>   c:\users\devansh\downloads\opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in
>   
> c:\users\devansh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
>   (from opencv-python==4.1.2.30) (1.18.0)
>  Installing collected
>   packages: opencv-python
>  Successfully installed
>   opencv-python-4.1.2.30
>  PS C:\Users\Devansh\Downloads> python
>   Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916
>   64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import cv2
> > > >  Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >    File "", line 1, in  ImportError: DLL load failed while
> > > >         importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

**

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV does not support Python 3.8,
According to official docs, Python version 3.7 is the highest version that is supported.

You can download Python 3.7 from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-377/

The latest bugfix release of Python 3.7 is Python 3.7.7

Hope this helps.